# Angular Material Mat-select with multiple selections : issue with display of selected values

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to customize the trigger label of a mat-select with multiple selections.

This is not my code.

The actual code looks like this :

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="filter.type === 'dropdown' && filter.multiple">
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="filterChanged(filter, $event)" [(value)]="filter.currentValue" [placeholder]="filter.name | translate" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filter.items" [value]="item.key">{{item.value | translate}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The filter is an object that looks like something like :

```
export interface TableFilterDef {
  id: string;
  httpId: string;
  type: FilterType;
  name: string;
  currentValue: string[]; => an array of strings containing the selected keys
  class?: string;
  items?: KeyValue[]; => an array of objects (key/value) containing all the possible values
  dialogComponent?: any;
  reset?: Function;
  multiple?: boolean;
}
```

items looks like :

```
export const logLevels: KeyValue[] = [
  {key: 'E', value: 'Errors'},
  {key: 'W', value: 'Warning'},
  {key: 'I', value: 'Info'},
  {key: 'D', value: 'Debug'}
];
```

For the sake of the demonstration I am selecting the following entries in the dropdown list : E (Errors) and W (Warnings)

First when I do not use the tag mat-select-trigger, I get the following label :

Errors, Warnings

Now when I use the folowing tag mat-select-trigger :

```
<mat-select-trigger>
      {{filter.currentValue ? filter.currentValue[0] : ''}}
      <span *ngIf="filter.currentValue?.length > 1">
        (+{{filter.currentValue.length - 1}} {{filter.currentValue?.length === 2 ? 'other' : 'others'}})
      </span>
    </mat-select-trigger>
```

I get the label :

E (+1 other)

So the sytem displays the keys but I would like to dsiplay the values instead like so :

Errors (+1 other)

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I suggest you make a mockup then put the screenshot inside the question as well.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz of your code?

Answer (score 0):

It is showing your `key` property because that is what you are binding in your `mat-option` as the value (`[value]="item.key"`):

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let item of filter.items" [value]="item.key">{{item.value | translate}}
</mat-option>
```

Your `currentValue` array will hold the values `['E', 'W']`. To solve your problem you could simply bind the `value` property instead of the `key` or you could bind the complete object, e.g. `[value]="item"`. If you bind the complete object, you would need to adjust your `TableFilterDef` so that `currentValue` is of type `KeyValue[]`. And your trigger would look like this:

```
<mat-select-trigger>
  {{filter.currentValue ? filter.currentValue[0].value : ''}}
  <span *ngIf="filter.currentValue?.length > 1">
    (+{{filter.currentValue.length - 1}} {{filter.currentValue?.length === 2 ? 'other' : 'others'}})
  </span>
</mat-select-trigger>
```